# get_post_meta() not working after javascript runs

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve data through my template in wordpress using get_post_meta() function. This works fine if I put the code above the div which is using a javascript, but it doesnt work if I put this function after the java script.
My php template file is as follows.
Here is the div using the javascript file ( lets call it div 1)`

```
        <div style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto; clear: both; ">

            <div style="width: 800px">
            <ul class='tabs'>
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
                <?php
                $i=1;
                while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <li><a href='#tab<?php echo $i; ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php $i++; endwhile;?>
            </ul>
           </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div style="background:#d0d8e0; position:relative; width: 96%; margin: -1% 4% 4% 2%; padding: 40px 0 20px 0; ">
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
                <?php
                $i=1;
                while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
                <div  id='tab<?php echo $i; ?>'>
                    <div class="tab" >
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; endwhile;?>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

       `</div></div>
```

And the code I am putting after this div to retrieve values from data base is( lets call it div 2)

```
<div class="group group-custom" >



            <?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-youtube-url', true); ?>

        <div style="float: left">  


   <iframe type="text/html" width="480" height="315"    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $url ); ?></iframe>
    </div>

        <div class="video-area">

            <h2><?php echo "" .get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-video-line',TRUE)?></h2>
             <br/>
            <p><?php echo "" .get_post_meta($post->ID,'wpcf-video-text',TRUE)?></p>
            <a class="button" href=""></a></div></div>
```

If I put the div 2 after div 1 in my php template, it doesn't work but if I switch the divs, it  works normally. Here is my javascript file ( which I dont see a problem)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler
        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

The live version of this work is http://cmi.pixstreammedia.com.s177734.gridserver.com/

Comment: always try tu put some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I have to use `<?php wp_reset_query() ?>` after the new wp_query function is over to restores the $wp_query and global post data to the original main query.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query